# xctool: how can I choose the iphone6 simulator?

Tags: ios, xctool

I am running test using `xctool`, and I would like to be able to choose the simulator. I am using the following line:

```
xctool -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace -scheme MyProject  test -reporter junit:test-results.xml -reporter teamcity -sdk iphonesimulator
```

However, the simulator that is open is the iPhone 4s simulator. Does anybody knows how to select the iPhone 6 simulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the -destination flag you can select a specific device to be run for your simulator :

```
-destination platform='iOS Simulator',OS=8.4,name='iPhone 6'
```

You should try the following command (replacing MyProject by the name of your project):

```
xctool -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace -scheme MyProject  test -reporter junit:test-results.xml -reporter teamcity -sdk iphonesimulator -destination platform='iOS Simulator',OS=8.4,name='iPhone 6'
```